# How to can I disable the auto reloading in Angular CLI?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Is there any way to disable the auto reloading in Angular ?

I tried to use `ng serve --live-reload false` but it didn't work.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue ?

Comment: what do u mean by reloading? when change the code it reload the application?

Comment: yes.is there any possibility?

Comment: What is your Angular Cli version?

Answer (score 0):

There is still no resolution - https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/3952

But it appears that it will be fixed in the next version. We will wait for it.